# Translating unicode representation of an emoji to an actual emoji

Tags: swift, unicode, emoji

I'm trying to add support for emoji shortcodes in my iOS app to replace them with the actual emoji. For example, turning :+1: into . The data I'm using is at https://github.com/iamcal/emoji-data, and the issue I'm having is it's displayed as `"unified": "1F44D"`, and i can't figure out how to turn that into an actual emoji.

Comment: The link you have shown is a huge database of emojis and I cannot understand why you get only `"unified": "1F44D"`. Please show your **input data** (which may include `+1`), your **current code**.

Comment: I think you really misunderstood.

Comment: Please explain what I am misunderstanding.

Comment: That one little line I included was just an example of what I need to translate to an emoji. Obviously I need to do it for all of them.

Comment: Even if it is just an example, you wrote  `it's displayed as "unified": "1F44D"` that means you have code which has displayed `"unified": "1F44D"`, no? I am just suggesting you should show the code.

Comment: The point you're missing is: I need to translate "1F44D" into an emoji.

Comment: What you are not understanding is, you wrote `it's displayed as "unified": "1F44D"`, so with showing your code, you have better chance to get the expected emoji sooner.

Comment: @JoshCaswell You are correct. That looks like what I need. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "1F44D" in this table is the unicode value in hex. Convert this to an integer, that to a UnicodeScalar, and that to a String or Character:

```
let unified = "1F44D"
if let value = Int(unified, radix: 16),
    let scalar = UnicodeScalar(value) {
    let string = String(scalar)
    print(string)
}
```

Comment: What about ones where they are like XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX. Do I need to split them and loop this then?

Comment: Ah; yeah, I see the sequences. Like 002A-FE0F-20E3. That's just three characters combined. ASTERISK, VARIATION SELECTOR-16 (i.e. "display previous character as emoji"), COMBINING ENCLOSING KEYCAP. Split on the `-` and put the three characters together in a String. Together that sequence combines to form *️⃣.